# How to combine aggregation queries - mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am having the following mongoDB document

```js
{
"location" : {
              "language" : null,
              "country" : "null",
              "city" : "null",
              "state" : null,
              "continent" : "null",
              "latitude" : "null",
             "longitude" : "null"
           },
"request" : [
             {
               "referrer" : "direct",
               "url" : "http://www.google.com/"
               "title" : "index page"
               "currentVisit" : 1401282897
               "visitedTime" : 1401282905
             },

             {
              "referrer" : "direct",
              "url" : "http://www.stackoverflow.com/",
              "title" : "index page"
              "currentVisit" : 1401282900
              "visitedTime" : 1401282905
             },
           ......
           ]
"uuid" : "109eeee0-e66a-11e3"
```

}

I am having four aggregation queries.

1. First Query:

   ```js
   [
    { "$match":{
             "request.1": {$exists:true}
    }},
    { "$match": { "request.currentVisit":{ 
           "$gte":1401282905, "$lte": 1401282985
    }}},
    { "$unwind": "$request" },
    { "$group": { 
         "_id": {
            "url":"$request.url"
     },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
   { "$sort":{ "count": -1 } }
   ]
   ```
2. Second Query:

   ```js
    [
      { "$match": {  
             "request":{ "$size": 1 }
      }},
      { "$match": { "request.currentVisit":{ 
           "$gte":1401282905, "$lte": 1401282985
      }}},
      { "$unwind": "$request" },
      { "$group": {
            "_id":{ 
               "url":"$request.url"
      },
      "count":{ "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "count": -1} }
     ]
   ```

3.Third Query:

```js
         [
         { "$match":{
            "request.1": { "$exists": true } 
         }},
         { "$match": { "request.currentVisit":{ 
               "$gte":1401282905, "$lte": 1401282985
         }}},
         { "$group": {
              "_id": "$uuid",
              "count":{ "$sum": 1 }
         }},
         { "$group": {
             "_id": null,
             "total": { "$sum":"$count" }}
         }}
        ]
```

1. Fourth Query:

   ```js
      [
       { "$match":{
           "request":{ "$size": 1 }
       }},
       { "$match": { "request.currentVisit":{ 
           "$gte":1401282905, "$lte": 1401282985
       }}},
      { "$group": {
             "_id":"$uuid",
             "count":{ "$sum": 1 }
       }},
       { "$group": {
            "_id":null,
            "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
       }}
      ]
   ```

#### Note:

1. Technology/programming - Node.js
2. Same database and same collection

#### Difference Between Queries:

First query will fetch the result for only `request size` 1

Second query will fetch the result for only `request size` more than one.

Same follows for third and fourth.

Is it possible to convert above four aggregation queries into single query to improve performance?

Comment: What is the difference between 1 and 2 and then 3 and 4? Each pair appears to be doing the same thing. Do you actually get different results?

Comment: I already worked out your update for what you were trying to do. There are big syntax errors in your post still. Embedding "match" within "match" is not valid. Also you seem to be missing that those initial "match" statements do not actually filter the array in which they are contained. The whole document is returned even where there is only one match. I presume that your intent is to count the "singular" matches and then only those array items that actually meet your conditions.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for pointing out there is some typo error

Comment: Can you also please confirm that you are actually intending to match the relevant items in the array to your criteria? It seems logical since why would just want the documents that had items that met this and then inspect those items counting things that do not match. But it would help if you said the "filter" was your intention.

Comment: Also, just for future reference. When you post sample data along with code that tries to "match" the criteria, then it does help if your data will actually "match" so someone can use it to test. You sample contains timestamp values outside the "range" you are asking for. So to test your query implementation, it helps if there is at least **one** result that will "match" the sample given

Comment: @NeilLunn Filtering is done intentionally. I want to display the data separately based on the request array size. I will edit my question to match the document.

Comment: This is getting a little too long just to clarify but if you fully read my comment then what I said is that you are **not** filtering the array content where it seems your intention is to do so. The correct way to respond to these comments is to either **explain** your intent or even better **change your post** to clearly say what it is you want to do. I/We need your actual answer to that.

Comment: Looking at this question, there is no good way to do subqueries. MongoDB is denormalized so performing a join (which requires normalization) is out of the question. You can simulate a join by running multiple queries though, as suggested in the answer to the linked question